# Read a file with Javascript and use its text

Tags: php, file

I need help with something i'm working on. 
I need my PHP code be able to read an uploaded file "A" and write a whole new file "B" with the very same words from A but in a different order

for example if A is

```
ABC 54 DOG 90 100
56 11 78 YOU 101
A C F H 99
```

B should be

```
DOG ABC 90 100 54
78 56 YOU 101 11
F A H 99 C
```

(so 3rd-1st-4th-5th-2nd. just an example)

What I had in mind was to do something like *fwrite($B,JavascriptFunction($A))*
but, once into the js part, I really don't know how to take the right word and put it into the text variable that javascriptfunction have to return.
I know I have to use a *.split('\n')* to deal with the different lines, but that's as far as I've figured out so far. I know it is probably a silly question but i'm really new to JS.

Thank you

Comment: What makes you think you can call javascript from php? PHP is a server-side language, javascript is client side.

Comment: Judging by the first sentence you really don't need any javascript. If you need `B` in javascript afterwards, you can just echo it out to a javascript variable (or return json, etc.).

Comment: yes, js was just a bad idea, I did it in php in no time. Maybe I was too curious to find out if it was possible to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont think you need Javascript to read file, but here it goes:

```
var fileContent='';
var theLocation='';

function readFileViaApplet(n) {
 document.f1.t1.value='Reading in progress...';
 document.ReadURL.readFile(theLocation);
 setTimeout("showFileContent()",100);
}

function showFileContent() {
 if (document.ReadURL.finished==0) {
  setTimeout("showFileContent()",100);
  return;
 }
 fileContent=document.ReadURL.fileContent;
 alert(fileContent); // do what you want with the content
}
```

Hope it helps